# Javascript, calling function from onClick() is not working

Tags: javascript

Trying to call a function from clicking on a cell. `alert(this.innertext)` and `window.close()` work independently and together when used with `onClick`. However, when I insert my own function it does not work. No errors in console on inspect.

```
mywin.document.write("<td onClick='test2()'>" + this.tArray[i] + "</td>");
function test2() {
    alert("hi");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `mywin` is a window, then you need to put `test2` into that window's global scope so it can be seen by the element. Add:

`myWin.test2 = () => alert('hi');`

But it would be much more elegant and manageable to insert elements using proper DOM methods and to attach listeners in the Javascript itself, rather than in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `mywin` is the window object (which is unnecessary).

**You need to add the whole table structure.**

```js
var mywin = window;
mywin.document.write("<table><tbody><tr><td onClick='test2()'>Hello!</td></tr></tbody></table>");

function test2(){ alert("hi");}
```

**Recommendation:**

Use the function `addEventListener`:

This approach uses the function `querySelectorAll` to loop and bind the event `click`.

```js
document.write("<table><tbody><tr><td class='clickable'>Ele</td></tr><tr><td class='clickable'>From SO</td></tr></tbody></table>");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.clickable'), function(td) {
  td.addEventListener('click', test2);
});

function test2(){ alert("hi");}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating the elements and creating the onclick with anonymous functions:

(replace yourTableRow with an object referencing the row in your table)

```
var cell = document.createElement("td");
cell.onclick = function (item) {
    return function () {
        test2(item);
    }
}(this.tArray[i]);

yourTableRow.appendChild(cell);

function test2(value) {
    console.log(value);
}
```